# FB dialog Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Is it possible to detect once the Facebook 'Share Link' button is clicked? Such as this one?

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctJJrBw7e-c&p[images][0]=http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/cat/cat-07.jpg&p[title]=Cat%20Video&p[summary]=Funny%20Cat%20Videos
```

Answer (score 0):

Not through the sharer.php - You may need to use an App for this, and use the FB.ui feed dialog. Which looks better anyway:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

It offers a callback function where you can detect if the post was published or the window was just closed without posting.

The user does not have to authorize your app, of course. You only have to initialize it:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for me using FB.ui? I've been trying to figure that out for a week, and still don't know how it works.

Comment: there´s an example code in the facebook docs, see the link i posted. i have also added some more links you will need.